# Reduce Selenium (Chrome) Traffic Usuage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I'm using a proxy with selenium-wire. The proxy is not free and I'm trying to reduce traffic usage for my selenium scraper as much as possible. Based on the traffic usage provided by the proxy provider, I noticed that Chrome is spending traffic on other links as well.

I managed to reduce traffic usage with the following options and switches (it might help someone in the future):

```
options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
options.add_argument('--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages')
options.add_argument('--disable-component-update')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-features=OptimizationGuideModelDownloading,OptimizationHintsFetching,OptimizationTargetPrediction,OptimizationHints')

prefs = {
            "download_restrictions": 3,
        }
self.options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

However, my scraper is still spending a lot of traffic on **edgedl.me.gvt1.com**. Is there any way in Selenium to somehow block traffic usage on this URL?

Thanks!